# Formula for Conditional probability doesn't make sense to me

Tags: probability

conditional probability is defined us:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

But if (and there is the part where i might be missing something) $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$ then:

$$ \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A) \cdot P(B)}{P(B)} = P(A) $$

which doesn't make any sense. Why would the formula exist in the first place. I'm confused.

Thanks for helping me :).

Comment: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ holds only when $A$ and $B$ are [independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29); in which case the result should not be surprising.

Comment: So how do i count $P(A|B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are dependent? What is formula for $P(A \cap B)$, $A$ and $B$ beeing dependent?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are dependent, there is no formula for $P(A \cap B)$ in terms of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$. In fact, depending on the events in question, $P(A \cap B)$ can be more-or-less anything.

Comment: I think it might be instructive to go through a bunch of examples. See: http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~jsbm/courses/311/conditioning.pdf

Comment: Thanx you all. I think i have it clear now. I'm little sorry there is no abstract formula for $P(A \cap B)$ that would be common for all kinds of probabilities.

Comment: The formula $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(B|A)\Pr(A)$ that you quoted is precisely such a formula. It is fairly often the case that we can find $\Pr(A)$ and $\Pr(B|A)$ quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to picture conditional probability is by viewing a Venn diagram.  (Sorry, I am doing this quickly and have not learned to generate one in MathJAX yet.)  In a simple diagram with two sets A and B, think of conditional probability as the ratio of the area of the intersection of the two circles to the area of the "given" circle (for A given B, that circle is B).

Imagine redefining the universe to be the given set (B in the previous example); the conditional probability is then the probability of A in that universe.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a more intuitive understanding that leads to the definition. (Sorry I'm not very good at latex.)
Take two events A and B, where they aren't necessarily independent. We seek to find the probability that both A and B occur. This turns out to be P(A and B).
Now, let's say A happens first. Therefore, P(A and B) = P(A)("something"). But since P(B|A) is defined as the probability of B occurring given A has already occurred, it is intuitively true that P(A and B) = P(A)P(B|A). Dividing P(A) on both sides yields the desired formula. 
Note that when the A and B are independent events, P(B|A) = P(B), because the events don't affect each others' outcomes. This simplifies to the regular formula for probabilities of independent events.